# implement web crawler service for ios app

Tags: ios

I want to develop an ios app on xcode which provide an web crawler service to the user. So I want to implement a server and implement a php web crawler in it which will server as a backend of my app. I had installed ubuntu server on my pc, is it possible to implement web crawler service on that. If not then which server can I use and how can I connect it with my ios app.

Comment: 404 Question not found

Comment: I have a web crawler written in php. I want to implement it on my server so that my app can send data to it and web crawler crawl web for url related to this data and return url to my app. How can I implement web crawler on my sever.

Comment: What have you tried, what is your code, where does it not work? Read the SO rules to understand what questions you should not ask and rethink yours afterwards... voted to close

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a question mark AND the only sentence i can figure out to be a question is wether or not it is possible, therefore:

**YES**

Comment: I want server to accept data from an ios app and use it as input to web crawler. How to setup this server?